# Grails Error While Running On NB

Tags: grails, netbeans, deployment

I made a Grails Project (v2.4.3) on NetBeans 6.9 (which is compatible with JDK 1.6 u24) but I get an error while running... Obviously I haven't an expertise or knowledge about Grails that's why I came here... Coz I know there people with lot of knowledge !.

[image]

I need to know If I have to configure something more; as I see there is a problem with the VM... I can't understand why...

Thankx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use filepatches without space in it. In this case change:

> C:\Mis%20Documentos\...

to for example:

> C:\grails\...